# Changes in template files are not shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an angularjs directive `'advertiser-row-directive'` that uses a template (in a different file for it's pretty long) called `'advertiser-row'`. The template itself includes another partial with `ng-include` for displaying some of the data called `'group-row.html'`. Each advertiser row has several group rows, the scope is the advertiser item.

When I change something in `advertiser-row.html` the browser (Firefox dev edition, but tried on Chrome as well) doesn't reload the changed template. Only when I change the directive itself than the template `advertiser-row.html` template is updated, but even then the `group-row.html` template used is still the cached one.

I had set the browser to disable the cache and I use 'hard reload', still no good. I assume that this due to some caching mechanism of angularjs itself, but I don't know how to disable it while developing.

How can I make sure my templates are always updated while developing? BTW, for development I serve my app as static files from a Django server.

Comment: Even when you shift-reload, you don't see the updated templates? That wouldn't be the angular template cache, since shift-reload would reset all of the JS, including the cache.

Comment: @deitch I've disabled caching in the browser all-together, but it never tries to fetch the new template. Instead, it uses some older version of the template.

Comment: Are you building them somehow? browserify or something similar that packages them up and messes with the cache?

Answer (score 0):

You need to force compile on the directive to accommodate changes of the inclusions that directive has. Make sure you have `compile` definition in your directive definition object, which returns updated link function with updated directive.

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer. I define a controller for my directive, I'm not sure how controllers and link functions relate. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear the cache manually. In Firefox, go to preferences -> privacy -> clear your recent history and select only 'cache' (unless you want to clear cookies, address etc.)

It seems that although I disabled the cache, these templates were already in the cache so firefox did not update the cache, but still used the cached templates. It seems to me it's a bug in Firefox.